# Webpage is displaying curly braces from expressions using Angular1.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As I'm new to Angular, I expect to run in to issues however this issue seems to be repeating itself off and on.

As I'm following a tutorial on learning Angular [here](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/1/section/3/video/1), I was learning about how to use expressions.

What I'm attempting to do is access an `gem`'s attributes and display them on the webpage. However, the object values are not being accessed and it is just displaying as so:

{{store.product.name}}

${{store.product.price}}

{{store.product.description}}

Add to Cart

Where as I want it to display as:

Dodecahaderon

$2.95

.  .  .

Add to Cart

I thought it may be due to the videos using Angular1.2 and I'm using 1.4 however I'm not sure. What am I doing wrong and how can I properly display the object attributes?

Here is the code:

```js
(function () {
 var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('StoreController', function(){
 this.product = gem;
});

var gem = {
 name: 'Dodecahaderon',
 price: 2.95,
 description: '. . . ',
 canPurchase = true,
 soldOut = true
};
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="store">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
  <div ng-hide="store.product.soldOut">
   <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
   <h2>${{store.product.price}}</h2>
   <p>{{store.product.description}}</p>
   <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase">Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually pointing to the angular library?

Comment: Replace `<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>` with `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That's a good point. I attempted to do apply your solution as well as linking to Angular 1.4.8, however it didn't work. It must be an issue with that.

Comment: did it work with the cdn link i provided, if you dont change the version?

Comment: After looking through my console and applying your cdn, it still had an error. However, I went back and realized that the console was recognizing errors in `gem`. It stated I shouldn't be using `=` when assigning the boolean values to `gem`. But after applying your cdn and changing `=` to `:`, it works. Thanks for looking over it man. Wouldn't have realized this without your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `gem` is definied outside the scope of the controller. Also, as gem as an object you must change `=` to `:`

You need to change your code to this and it works

```
(function () {
  var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('StoreController', function(){

  this.item = {
    name: 'Dodecahaderon',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '. . . ',
    canPurchase : true,
    soldOut : true
  };


});

})();
```

And your html to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="store">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div ng-hide="store.product.soldOut">
      <h1>{{store.item.name}}</h1>
      <h2>${{store.item.price}}</h2>
      <p>{{store.item.description}}</p>
      <button ng-show="store.item.canPurchase">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Also, you may need to replace your reference to angular from `<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>` to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></sc‌​ript>`

Comment: Thanks but also the issue was I was using `=` when assigning boolean values to `gem`. I needed to use `:` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your angular library is not referenced correctly. Open your console window and make sure the angular script reference is actually working.